# Проектирование базы данных при DDD (Domain-Driven Design)

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, проектирование, ddd

Постараюсь **кратко** описать мой теоретический и не очень актуальный, но интересующий вопрос.

В подходе *DDD* при проектировании приложения отталкиваются от проектирования доменной логики. Если есть у кого-то опыт, посоветуйте, как тогда проектировать базу данных. А то подход *DDD* мне теоретически понятен когда незыблемая *БД* уже есть. А если ее нет и ведется командная разработка и когда одну часть системы делает одна команда разработчиков, а другую - другая, то уже совсем не понятно. Если сначала проектировать *БД* для всей системы, то название *domain-dd* не совсем себя оправдывает, так как отталкиваемся уже не от проектирования домена, а от проектирования *БД*...

---

Постараюсь теперь **подробнее** описать вопрос, с приведением простого теоретического **примера** конкретной **ситуации**, в которой этот вопрос может возникнуть.

В *DDD* есть два термина:

- *Ubiquitous language* - повсеместный язык
- *Bounded context* - ограниченный контекст

То есть одна и та же сущность должна быть по-разному спроектирована в зависимости от того, в каком контексте она используется.

**Например**, если рассмотреть какую-нибудь систему *ERP* для планирования ресурсов предприятия, в котором сотрудники сидят и с помощью приборов делают работы. В этой системе могут быть следующие сущности:

- *Сотрудники*
- *Приборы*
- *Работы*

У системы могут быть две функции:

- Вести учет *Приборов*, то есть за каким сотрудником числится какой прибор.
- Вести учет *Работ*, то есть какие работы были или будут сделаны и какие сотрудники и приборы в этом участвуют.

На сколько я понимаю, понятие *ограниченного контекста* (*bounded context*) введено, чтобы разграничить проектирование приложения на части, чтобы отдать эти части для разработки разным *командам* программистов. На сколько я понимаю, в данном примере ограниченные контексты это и есть две функции системы: учет пользователей и учет приборов.

Понятие повсеместного языка - на сколько я понимаю это когда заказчик и разработчик разговаривают на одном языке. В нашем примере заказчика два: тот отдел организации, который следит за инвентарем и тот отдел, который следит за выполнением работ.

Если взять отдел инвентаризации, то *Прибор* в данном контексте должен иметь одни поля, например, модель, инвентарный номер, и т.д. А в контексте учета работ, у *Прибора* должны быть другие поля, но некоторые совпадают: так же модель, но еще и технические характеристики, и установленная ОС, ну а инвентарный номер здесь не нужен. Так же и у *Сотрудника* разные поля в разных контекстах.

То есть, **ситуация** такая, что одной команде разработчиков дали разрабатывать контекст инвентаризации, а другой - учета работ. При этом для одной команды *прибор* и *сотрудник* - это одно, а для другой команды *прибор* и *сотрудник* это другое.

**Вопрос**. Как двум командам разработчиков, работающим над разными частями системы и видящих логические сущности приложения по-разному, приступить к проектированию базы данных? Ведь если они сначала скооперируются и сделают общую *базу данных*, где есть *сотрудники* со всеми полями и дополнительными таблицами и *приборы* со всеми полями и дополнительными таблицами, то это уже будет не совсем DDD, так как отталкиваемся не от проектирования домена, а от проектирования данных.

Так же интересуют любые советы и если кто поделится своим опытом, о том, как проектировать *БД* когда над системой работают несколько разных групп людей с разным видением...

Comment: Думаю следует начать с построения моделей в какомнибудь Power Designer, в нем расписать все сущьности, и уже на базе моделей генерить базы данных и давать таски разработчикам

Comment: Разные сущности - с разной логикой, следовательно разные поля, и разные базы - если не с физической, то с концептуальной точки зрения. Вы хотите чудесный DDD смешать с паттерном Big Ball Of Mud где люди вместо сервисов через базу интегрируются. Я ничего против BBM не имею, просто если у вас стоит поставленное требование/процесс что "сначала скооперируются и сделают общую базу данных, где есть сотрудники со всеми полями и дополнительными таблицами и приборы со всеми полями и дополнительными таблицами" - тут либо есть DDD, либо нет, не бывает немножко DDD, так только худшее из двух миров будет.

Comment: Тут здравый смысл подсказывает что сущности разные - если у них общее инвентарный номер или артикул прибора, то по артикулу и можно сопоставлять, а так это совершенно разные сервисы то что вы описали. Или даже можно отдельно вывести понятие/сущность - инвентарная единица. Во втором случае непонятно как у вас будет прибор без номера.

Comment: @Dmitry Спасибо за коммент! Действительно, если база данных одна и требования не меняются то хорошо расписать сущности и на их основе генерировать базу. Наверное, мое непонимание возникает именно для ситуации, когда в начале разработки требования до конца не ясные, а проясняются по ходу дела...

Comment: @Boris Treukhov Большое спасибо! Очень понравился комментарий. Поправьте меня, если понял неправильно. Для такой сущности, как прибор, создавать одну общую таблицу БД с ID и общими полями. А потом две таблицы, которые расширяет общую своими полями для каждого из контекстов... Так?

Comment: @AndreyKomissarov, всегда пожалуйста. По поводу ситуации когда требования доконца не ясны, это работа бизнес аналитика, он просто обязан подготовить ЧТЗ к которому не подкопаться, а эта работа занимает иногда даже несколько лет. В зависимости от масштаба проекта конечно. На протежении всей работы аналитика постоянно вносятся хотелки, в зависимости от погружения в процесс, вообщем эта работа довольно сложная, но на выходе качественная продукция. Ну и естественно ни каких еженедельных релизов, это самое большое зло которое выдумали на западе.

Comment: @Dmitry, Очень интересно! Если Вы имеете ввиду, что Agile - зло, которое придумали на западе, то не знаю, согласиться или нет, не имею пока своего мнения. Но слышал о многих (3-5 шт.) примерах, когда Agile на западе сработал, при том, что Waterfall провалился. Может быть это вопрос философский и подразумевает различный менталитет народов :)

Comment: @AndreyKomissarov, Agile уместен в легком софте для мобильных устройств, когда нужно срочно застолбить рынок. В больших проектах это очень коварное зло, когда заказчик будет за каждый баг выносить мозг и выставлять штрафные санкции.

Comment: @Dmitry, все это очень интересно. Наверняка то, что Вы говорите про Agile часто правда. Все же.. Бывает, что разработка ведется не при дневном свете (когда требования ясны перед началом разработки), а ночью с искуственным освещением или с даже фонариком. Потом, когда проект уже сделан, возникают новые требования по дополнению функционала... Возможно, правильное решение, это выверенное и проектирование костяка приложения с заделом на будущее. То есть, сделать так, чтобы новый функционал хорошо ложился на основу. Про Agile все же интересно побольше узнать, действительно ли это зло :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> На сколько я понимаю, понятие ограниченного контекста (bounded context) введено, чтобы разграничить проектирование приложения на части, 
>   чтобы отдать эти части для разработки разным командам программистов.

Мне кажется, что в первую очередь здесь имеет смысль разделение на модули, а возможность разработки различными командами это уже следствие такого разделения.

Так как у сущности может быть множество атрибутов которые, зачастую, используются небольшими группами в различных функциях проще сразу разделить такую сущность на эти группы атрибутов и использовать их независимо, чем везде
таскать одну и туже сущность большая часть которой, в заданном контексте, не нужна и образует только лишнюю связанность кода.

---

У Вас есть сервер приложений где описана модель Ваших данных и бизнес-логика которая умеет менять состояние этой модели. 
Модели должно быть все равно где и как хранится ее состояние.

В Вашей ситуации главное то, как выглядит модель данных на сервере приложений и то, как реализована ее бизнес-логика. 
Ведь описание сущностей и их атрибуты ровно как и методы этих сущносетй должны быть понятны всем участникам процесса и соответсвовать тому как они все себе это представляют
опираясь на общий язык.

На сколько я понимаю, *DDD* подразумевает длительный процесс выработки модели предметной области в течении которого она будет достаточно часто меняться пока более менее не устаканится.
В таком случае сразу скооперироваться и сделать общую базу данных так просто не получится, так как модель еще толком не ясна. Поэтому, в первую очередь, Вы будете создавать и менять 
модель данных на сервере приложений и уже во вторую очередь придумывать как она будет хранится. Но это не означает то, что в процессе изменения модели данных так же сильно должно меняться и хранилище данных (может меняться только слой абстракции в виде представлений).

---

Что касается БД - то тут можно пойти по разному. У вас есть база данных которая хранит состояние Вашей модели и осуществляет проверку целостности данных. 
На БД часто налагают различные технические требования так, что вопрос распределения данных по таблицам может, в большей степени, 
относится к решению этих технических проблем, а не к соответствию 1 в 1 с Вашей моделью данных.

То, что у сотруника в разных контекстах есть как общие атрибуты так и частные
напоминает наследование. А для наследования придумали различные способы хранения данных в таблицах, такие как [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html), [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) и [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html).

В Вашем случае вполне может быть подходящим второй способ. Тогда Вы сможете определить и выделить общие черты нужных сущностей и положить их в одну таблицу позволив разным командам создать таблицы для атрибутов этой сущности относящихся только к их задачам.
Или даже третий способ для начала, чтобы быть полностью независимыми друг от друга.
У каждого подхода будут как свои плюсы так и минусы как в плане добавления\удаления атрибутов так и в плане взаимопересечения команд и дублирования данных.

Независимо от варианта со структурой таблиц стоит использовать дополнительный слой абстракции над этими таблицами в виде представлений. Такой подход позволит склеить разные или разделить одну таблицы.
В дальнейшем, когда сама модель данных перестанет сильно меняться, можно будет рассмотреть первый вариант. Это должно будет упростить логику приложения и, возможно, снизить размер сохраненного состояния.

---

Ну и когда над одной БД работают различные группы людей особенно с разным видением я думаю, что стоит в первую очередь выработать какие-то общие правила (стандарты) как минимум в области именования обьектов.

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ! Обязательно изучу, как только получится.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Главное - чтобы это принесло Вам какую либо пользу =)

Comment: Да, здорово! Получил ответ на свой вопрос, спасибо! Единственное, под слоем представлений в бд Вы подразумевали то, что называется вьюшками в sql server?

Comment: Да, view, все верно.

Comment: Еще, напрашивается автоматическая генерация кода базы данных на основе доменных сущностей. Когда-то немного поискал такую библиотеку для c# и sql server, жалко, но не нашел...

Comment: Я думаю тут все зависит от ... Не забывайте, что уже существующую структуру БД нельзя просто поменять если в ней уже есть данные. Это все равно придётся делать вручную. И далеко не факт, что автоматически созданная  структура будет эффективна на больших объёмах данных. Но,если хотите это попробовать, то есть [Entity framework code first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj193542.aspx) оно и структуру базы сделает и скрипты для её обновления тоже.